# Is it possible to use Python to write cross-platform apps for both iOS and Android?

Tags: python, android, ios, cross-platform, beeware

Is it possible to use Python to write cross-platform apps for both iOS and Android

Comment: [duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216890/target-both-android-and-iphone)

Comment: @keyser i am not convinced by the selected answer of that question, I think it can be used and to confirm I asked that question

Comment: Has this changed at all?

Comment: Is using [pyside](http://wiki.qt.io/PySide), [pyqtdeploy](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtdeploy/intro) a viable option in 2018?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For Android Google provides something called ASE (Android Scripting Environment) which allows scripting languages (Python included) to run on Android. More details [here](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2009/06/introducing-android-scripting.html)

For iOS, it might be quite a bit more complicated (and I'd advise to check the latest version of iOS SDK agreement to check the current state of the law - apple tends to allow & disallow such apps periodically). For the technical part you might need to interface between Python & Objective C as well as do some wizardry to statically link all the libraries Python requires; full details are available [here](http://www.saurik.com/id/5).
Another approach for iOS Python development would be to embed a Python interpreter into you app and distribute your Python script with it (so to play nicely with Apple rules). In this case your Python application would be a Python interpreter which is packaged with your script and runs it automatically.

Second option is to use Kivy framework(kivy.org) - it's a framework to write touch-friendly applications in Python and package them for different platforms. It's had Android support for a while, and recently added iOS support

Comment: also this is precisely the aim of Kivy (http://kivy.org/) - it's a framework to write touch-friendly applications in Python and package them for different platforms. It's had Android support for a while, and recently added iOS support

Comment: Python 3.3+ to iOS is not supported by Kivy yet.

Answer (score 85):

An option is [kivy](http://kivy.org): a cool cross platform Python framework which works for Android, Win7, Linux, MacOSX and iOS.

Update: kivy project is growing daily, now supports also Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 5):

For writing a GUI applicaion you can use the [Toga](https://pybee.org/project/projects/libraries/toga/) library,then package it with [briefcase](https://pybee.org/project/projects/tools/briefcase/) into a Android and/or iOS app (or Windows, Linux, macOS etc).

**Note:** the project is still in alpha state but under rapid development.

Answer (score 3):

As @piertoni mentioned, [BeeWare](https://pybee.org) enables native iOS & Android apps to be written in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You can try and combine [brython](/questions/tagged/brython) and [cordova](/questions/tagged/cordova). The Brython wiki describes [how to write an Android app using Brython](https://github.com/brython-dev/brython/wiki/Writing-an-Android-application), which might provide the necessary information to do this also using Cordova. I haven't tested this yet, but it sounds promising. You should however be aware that due to its nature, Brython cannot support x86-compiled packages such as OpenCV (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42210710/321973)). On the other hand, if you know a bit about JavaScript / HTML5, you can use the WebView native functions, e.g. http://www.brython.info/gallery/three.html.

Answer (score 0):

There's [FireMonkey (FMX)](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python).

FMX is a fairly new framework for developing cross-platform applications using Python, but I can honestly say that it is the best one currently available!

It's far better than all the other GUI Python Frameworks. With FMX you can develop with a single code base for Windows, MacOS, Android, and Linux.

iOS is not yet supported, but it is planned for in the near future.

I think FMX is worth keeping an eye on.